# Send video stream from a webcam to a websocket in C

Tags: c, opencv, raspberry-pi, video-capture

I'm trying to send the video stream from my webcam to a websocket in C. I've already etablish the websocket, but the video capture doen't work.

I'm trying to use mutex, but I get error during compilation.

I use this function to get the image :

```
void *send_images(void *arg) {
    CvCapture* capture = cvCreateCameraCapture(CV_CAP_ANY);
    if (!capture) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Failed to open the webcam\n");
        return NULL;
    }

    while (1) {
        pthread_mutex_lock(&wsi_mutex);
        if (!global_wsi) {
            pthread_mutex_unlock(&wsi_mutex);
            break;
        }

        IplImage* frame = cvQueryFrame(capture);
        if (!frame) {
            fprintf(stderr, "Failed to capture a frame from the webcam\n");
            break;
        }

        CvMat stub, *mat = cvGetMat(frame, &stub);
        CvMat *buf = cvEncodeImage(".jpg", mat, 0);

        size_t encoded_len;
        char* base64_encoded = base64_encode((const unsigned char *)buf->data.ptr, buf->cols, &encoded_len);
        if (!base64_encoded) {
            fprintf(stderr, "Failed to encode the image in Base64\n");
            break;
        }

        unsigned char* buffer = (unsigned char*) malloc(LWS_PRE + encoded_len);
        memcpy(buffer + LWS_PRE, base64_encoded, encoded_len);
        lws_write(global_wsi, buffer + LWS_PRE, encoded_len, LWS_WRITE_TEXT);
        free(buffer);
        free(base64_encoded);

        cvReleaseMat(&buf);

        pthread_mutex_unlock(&wsi_mutex);

        usleep(100000); // Sleep for 100ms
    }

    cvReleaseCapture(&capture);

    return NULL;
}
```

Comment: "but I get error during compilation." please be more specific. What error message do you get?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.